# What type of iOS project template should I start with?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode-template

I'm building a project similar in design/scope to [Invoice2Go](http://www.iphone-invoice2go.com/) and was wondering what the appropriate iOS project type would be to start with in XCode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, from the most basic template (`Window-based Application`) you can setup any app. It seems Invoice2Go makes use of a tab bar, so the `Tab Bar application` seems most convenient, though you can add a tab bar to the Window-based Application as well.

Personally I like to start with a `Window-based Application` most of the time, this gives me the most flexible starting-point.

Answer (score 0):

I think the app looks like Tab Bar based application. You can try using that template. Of course you can start with simple Window based app, but you need to wire it all up yourself.